# How to filter association_ids for an ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, has-many

In a domain like this:

```
 class User
  has_many :posts
  has_many :topics, :through => :posts
 end
 class Post
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :topic
 end
 class Topic
   has_many :posts
 end
```

I can read all the Topic ids through `user.topic_ids` but I can't see a way to apply filtering conditions to this method, since it returns an `Array` instead of a `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

The problem is, given a User and an *existing* set of Topics, marking the ones for which there is a post by the user. I am currently doing something like this:

```
 def mark_topics_with_post(user, topics)
   # only returns the ids of the topics for which this user has a post
   topic_ids = user.topic_ids 
   topics.each {|t| t[:has_post]=topic_ids.include(t.id)}
 end
```

But this loads all the topic ids regardless of the input set. Ideally, I'd like to do something like

```
 def mark_topics_with_post(user, topics)
   # only returns the topics where user has a post within the subset of interest
   topic_ids = user.topic_ids.where(:id=>topics.map(&:id))
   topics.each {|t| t[:has_post]=topic_ids.include(t.id)}
 end
```

But the only thing I can do concretely is

```
 def mark_topics_with_post(user, topics)
   # needlessly create Post objects only to unwrap them later
   topic_ids = user.posts.where(:topic_id=>topics.map(&:id)).select(:topic_id).map(&:topic_id)
   topics.each {|t| t[:has_post]=topic_ids.include(t.id)}
 end
```

Is there a better way? 
Is it possible to have something like `select_values` on a association or scope? 
FWIW, I'm on rails 3.0.x, but I'd be curious about 3.1 too.

**Why am I doing this?**

Basically, I have a result page for a semi-complex search (which happens based on the Topic data only), and I want to mark the results (Topics) as stuff on which the user has interacted (wrote a Post).

So yeah, there is another option which would be doing a join [Topic,Post] so that the results come out as marked or not from the search, but this would destroy my ability to cache the Topic query (the query, even without the join, is more expensive than fetching only the ids for the user)

Notice the approaches outlined above *do work*, they just feel suboptimal.

Comment: Maybe you can describe why you are doing what you are doing. Sometimes going up the abstraction reveals simplifications in the requirements (Snickers vs Belgian chocolate).

Answer (score 4):

I think that your second solution is almost the optimal one (from the point of view of the queries involved), at least with respect to the one you'd like to use.

`user.topic_ids` generates the query:

```
SELECT `topics`.id FROM `topics` 
INNER JOIN `posts` ON `topics`.`id` = `posts`.`topic_id` 
WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1
```

if `user.topic_ids.where(:id=>topics.map(&:id))` was possible it would have generated this:

```
SELECT topics.id FROM `topics` 
INNER JOIN `posts` ON `topics`.`id` = `posts`.`topic_id` 
WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1 AND `topics`.`id` IN (...)
```

this is exactly the same query that is generated doing: `user.topics.select("topics.id").where(:id=>topics.map(&:id))`

while `user.posts.select(:topic_id).where(:topic_id=>topics.map(&:id))` generates the following query:

```
SELECT topic_id FROM `posts` 
WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1 AND `posts`.`topic_id` IN (...)
```

which one of the two is more efficient depends on the data in the actual tables and indices defined (and which db is used).

If the topic ids list for the user is long and has topics repeated many times, it may make sense to group by topic id at the query level:

```
user.posts.select(:topic_id).group(:topic_id).where(:topic_id=>topics.map(&:id))
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered that the join is necessary, which makes sense if there is no referential integrity and duplicate values. The problem with the posts/select/map solution is that it creates a lot more objects in ruby land (at least one object  with 8 fields, 4 hashes, two strings) just to get me a Fixnum, plus a useless loop, when they are  unnecessary. This is obviously not a huge deal, but it just feels wrong.

Comment: yep, you are correct and It does feel wrong, my point was that the topic_ids method itself follows exactly the topics/select/map route. The only (ugly) way to avoid instantiating active records I can think of involves executing the sql query directly ...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your Topic model has a column named id you can do something like this

```
Topic.select(:id).join(:posts).where("posts.user_id = ?", user_id)
```

This will run only one query against your database and will give you all the topics ids that have posts for a given user_id

Comment: but that is not what I need: I already have a list of Topic objects, I only want to flag those that have a relation post in common with the user.